# Use fiddler only for some processes

Tags: fiddler

I was wondering if I could use Fiddler2 on only some processes instead of all applications which use system proxy settings. I know there is a filter option in Fiddler2, but as far as I know, it only *hides* information and the traffic is captured anyway.

Comment: It entirely depends on what your desired target process is. Some processes only use the system proxy (e.g. IE) and reconfiguring it so only an individual process uses the proxy is non-trivial. In other cases (e.g. Firefox and Opera) it's easy to configure only those products to go through Fiddler. But the real question is *why* you hope to do this... if you're worried about impacting behavior of applications you don't need to debug, there are simple steps you can take to reduce the impact of that...

Comment: Well, I'm aware of that, but I'm looking for a simple way to do this. As for the second part ("WHY"): I think connections made directly from my apps have more consistency compared to Fiddler2. By that I mean, when I use Fiddler2, many of the connections die in heavy download situations.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**There is a "Any Processes" button on fiddler toolbar. Drag the icon to a window to show traffic from only that process. Click the icon again to cancel the filter.
This is the best and simplest way to filter by process.**

Or, in File menu, don't check the "Capture Traffice" item. Then set proxy in your others applications which need to be captured by fiddler.

If you capture HTTPS, open the https config dialog(Fiddler Options >> HTTPS), you'll see a list box with these list items:

- ...from all processes
- ...from browsers only
- ...from non-browsers only
- ...from remote client only

Comment: Thank you. It's not **exactly** what I was looking for, but it solves my problem. I think the Fiddler team should implement a filtering mechanism like `Proxifier` though.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a video which shows you how to filter by processes in fiddler. Towards the end of the video, you can learn how to filter by browser or even the tab of a browser.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qZYl3a60-Uc

Steps (Fiddler 4.3x) -

1. Fiddler > Filters Tab
2. Use filters - check it!
3. Client processes : Show only Traffic from - check it! > Choose your process (a browser or tab in browser) from the adjacent drop down menu.
4. Actions button > Run filterset now - click it!

Done !

Answer (score 0):

To use Fiddler for capturing traffic from a **specific process/Application** fiddler has provided a option - **"Any Process"**
[image: Any Process Option]

Steps :

- Open/Launch the application which you want to monitor.
- Select **"Any Process"** option and Drag it to the you application.
- Now you have restricted Fiddler to capture the traffic from a specific Process/Application.

Comment: No, Fiddles still captures traffic from all processes